# Capture sound waves

Tags: software, recommendations, waveform

I'm trying to capture sound wave patterns from mp3s. At the moment I'm doing screen grabs from audacity, then fixing them up in photoshop. Does anyone know any other software I could use for this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Adobe Audition.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be very much about design.

Comment: Cheers Ryan. I want to manipulate the waves when captured, I guess that could be classed as design.

Comment: When you have a question about that you know where to ask :) Just might be more on topic right now in either the sound exchange or superuser since its more about capturing the sound waves at this point then anything design related.

Comment: I think image capture questions are on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [Sonic Visualiser](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/). It's free, has image export built in and is generally designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Alternatively, you could download a demo of iZotope RX4 - should provide you with both waveform and spectrum images.

Comment: Cheers guys thats what I was after.

Comment: @christiancoriolis: Nope - Sonic is the best! ;)

Comment: Certainly for the price it is :-)